# Can d3's transition and rotation play well together?

Tags: javascript, rotation, d3.js, transition, jsfiddle

Transitions in combination with rotations have odd results.

Here is a fiddle with my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/emperorz/E3G3z/1/
Try clicking on each square to see the varying behaviour.

Please forgive the hacked code, but if I use transition with rotation (and x/y placement) then it loops about.

I have tried:

1) all in the transform (rotate then translate), and that seems mostly okay. A little wobbly.

2) just rotate in the transform, positioned using x/y attributes. Flies all over the place, but ends up at the correct spot. Very weird.

<strike>3) all in the transform (translate then rotate), flies away, and ends up in the (completely) wrong place.</strike>

Hmmm. Strange.

Is there a correct approach to rotating shapes with transitions?

Intuitively, it would be good if the second option worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To rotate an SVG object on an arbitrary axis, you need two transformations: `translate` (to set the axis) and `rotate`.  What you really want is to apply the `translate` fully first and then rotate the already moved element, but it appears that `translate` and `rotate` operate independently and simultaneously. This ends at the right place, but animating the `translate` is essentially moving the axis during rotation, creating the wobble. You can isolate the `translate` from the `rotate` by having them occur at separate places in the SVG element hierarchy. For example, take a look at the following:

```
<g class="outer">
    <g class="rect-container">
        <rect class="rotate-me" width=200 height=100 />
    </g>
</g>
```

You can center the `<rect>` on (0,0) with `translate (-100, -50)`. It will wobble if you apply your rotation to the `<rect>` element, but it will rotate cleanly if you `rotate` the `g.rect-container` element. If you want to reposition, scale, or otherwise transform the element further, do so on `g.outer`. That's it. You now have full control of your transforms.

Finding a `<rect>`'s center is easy, but finding the center of a `<path>`, `<g>`, etc. is much harder. Luckily, a simple solution is available in the [.getBBox()](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#getBBox) method (code in CoffeeScript; see below for a JavaScript version*):

```
centerToOrigin = (el) ->
    boundingBox = el.getBBox()
    return {
        x: -1 * Math.floor(boundingBox.width/2),
        y: -1 * Math.floor(boundingBox.height/2) 
    }
```

You can now center your element/group by passing the non-wrapped element (using D3's `.node()` method)

```
group = d3.select("g.rotate-me")
center = centerToOrigin(group.node())
group.attr("transform", "translate(#{center.x}, #{center.y})")
```

For code that implements this on a both a single `<rect>` and  `<g>` of of 2 `rect`s with repositioning and scaling, [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdickert/hQBEw/1/).

---

*Javascript of the above code:

```
var center, centerToOrigin, group;

centerToOrigin = function(el) {
  var boundingBox;
  boundingBox = el.getBBox();
  return {
    x: -1 * Math.floor(boundingBox.width / 2),
    y: -1 * Math.floor(boundingBox.height / 2)
  };
};

group = d3.select("g.rotate-me");
center = centerToOrigin(group.node());
group.attr("transform", "translate(" + center.x + ", " + center.y + ")");
```

Comment: You rule, the first paragraph and example are priceless! Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

iirc translate is relative to 0,0 whereas rotate is around the center point of the object

As such, because your shapes are offset from 0,0 (e.g. 100,200, or 200,100) they end up migrating when translated.  This can be seen by changing the offsets for Diamond3 to [50,50] - much smaller migration around the screen

The solution would be rebase the 0,0 point to the center of the diamond.  There is a way to do this in D3 - but I can't remember what it is off the top of my head :(

Comment: Possibly I am misunderstanding you, but really, 1 & 2 should be identical. They end up in identical places (there is no geometric difference to the end-points of the transition), but during the transition, the paths are great looping epicycles. I'm guessing the small wobbles are due to errors in the arctan function, or similar, but the big loops are just odd.

Comment: In the example, when you click, you are adding the X,Y values to the start point again (and again and again).  So, when the page loads, you translate Diamond2 out to 100,200.  When the user clicks, diamond2 is rotated 65 degrees - and translated *again* by 100,200.  The different behaviour is caused by either rotating first, then translating, rotating while translating, or translating first, and the different in scale is caused by the different in the translation values.  To prove this, edit your fiddle to remove 'Diamond2.x' and 'Diamond2.y' from the click handler transform.

Comment: No it isn't repeatedly changing the translation. The rotation increments, but the translation stays exactly the same.

Comment: I've cleaned things up slightly. The 'problem' seems to be in the way the interpolation is done. Hmmm. I might do a pure svg animation and see if it does the same thing.

Comment: OK. After messing with native SVG animations, and wrestling with absolute versus relative positioning and rotation (sooo unintuitive), I now know the way to avoid this problem. So, here's my workaround till I get an answer, though I'm not holding my breath. Construct all shapes around the origin. Define your own relative frame using group and transform (to avoid the absolute position but relative rotation unpleasantness). Transition each individually and separately. Now I need to see if the transitions run in parallel (a la SVG), or sequentially. In any case, no wobble, yay!

Comment: parallel. Job done. Thanks for spending time on this logical :).

Comment: @emperorz, could you post code that demonstrates your solution? I just encountered this issue and am still wrapping my head around the answer.