# Combining translate and rotate with D3

Tags: d3.js

Quite possibly this repeats some of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494447/can-d3s-transition-and-rotation-play-well-together), but the code is overly-complicated and the OP hasn't added solution code.  And this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349925/d3-transition-rotation-and-translation) is no longer replicable.

I'm trying to figure out how to combine rotations and translations in the right order.  It's possible to rotate around the origin [as in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/vRc6T/).  But when we follow this with a translation the original rotation [is undone](http://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/vRc6T/1/).

Is it possible to structure this for correct sequential application?

**jsfidle code:**

HTML:

```
<script src="http://d3.geotheory.co.uk/d3-transform.js"></script>
```

SVG:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 300);

//Draw the Rectangle
var rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 50).attr("height", 100)
    .style("fill", "purple");

var rotate = d3.svg.transform().rotate(-45);
var translate = d3.svg.transform().translate(200, 100);

rect.attr('transform', rotate);

var rect2 = rect.attr('transform', rotate);
rect2.attr('transform', translate);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're creating two different transformations. Assigning one doesn't add to the other. That is, in doing

```
rect2.attr('transform', translate);
```

you're undoing the first one, as it is overwritten.

To have both, add them both to one transition, e.g.

```
var rotateTranslate = d3.svg.transform().rotate(-45).translate(200, 100);
rect2.attr('transform', rotateTranslate);
```

To do this dynamically, you'll need to do something like this.

```
.attr("transform", function() {
    return d3.svg.transform()
        .translate(200, 100)
        .rotate(-45)
        .translate(-d3.select(this).attr("width")/2, -d3.select(this).attr("height")/2)();
}
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vRc6T/4/).

Comment: Cheers. I tried chaining approach before, but it implemented translate before rotate. Now I realise d3 is applying them in reverse order (right to left) - so it should actually be `.translate(200, 100).rotate(-45)`.

Comment: Of course rotation is around the origin, so there needs to be another operation to rotate around object's centroid. However `var rotateTranslate = d3.svg.transform().translate(200, 100).rotate(-45).translate(-this.width/2, -this.height/2);` fails (_Unexpected value translate(200,100) rotate(-45) translate(NaN,NaN) parsing transform attribute._) I think because 'this' doesn't refer correctly to the object we want to translate. What would you recommend?

Comment: You can use this inside a function to set an attribute like any of the other things, e.g. `d3.selectAll("..").attr("transform", function() { return d3.svg.transform().translate(200, 100).rotate(-45).translate(-this.width/2, -this.height/2); });`

Comment: Ok, in the fiddle you weren't selecting anything, so the code didn't run, but my example wasn't correct either. `this.width` doesn't work unless you set the width explicitly as an attribute and you need to call the function that `transform` returns. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks Lars that's useful

Answer (score 21):

If you're looking to do this in D3 version 4.x+ you can do it like so:

```
.attr('transform', 'translate(200,100)rotate(-45)')
```

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1345853