# Rotate svg path around its centre d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a simple cog wheel drawn in illustrator. I've placed the svg markup in the index page and all is well. I can access it by its id.

The code below is part of a function that is executed on that time period so I don't need to worry about the time element.

I've looked around and am not understanding the examples I've found. This is what I have:

```
var motor=d3.select('#wheel')
motor.attr('transform', 'rotate(0, 0, 2)');
```

I want to rotate a couple of degrees every 300 milliseconds.

Comment: var rotate = d3.svg.transform().rotate(amountOfRotation) then motor.attr('transform', rotate); is that what you want ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030473/combining-translate-and-rotate-with-d3

Comment: No sorry that doesn't seem to work

Comment: could you mock up a fiddle so we could give it a go

Comment: Terribly sorry, don't know how to use it. Fairy new to this. This nearly works but the wheel jumps to the left about 30 pixels and doesn't continue to rotate motor.attr("transform", "rotate(2)")

Comment: did the answer solve your problem ?

Comment: No sorry, just having to do other stuff at the moment, but thanks for asking

Comment: you need to mock up an example. Go into this link : http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/7218/ past HTML top left, CSS top right and Javascript bottom left. I have inmorted D3 for you so shouldnt be difficult. Otherwise your problem is difficult to solve

Answer (score 2):

Your original code doesn't seem very functional (the commas in rotate are not needed). So taking those out, your statement is asking the svg to rotate by 0 degrees around the x, y coordinates 0, 2 (2 pixels down from the top-left corner).  What you want is closer to:

```
var motor=d3.select('#wheel')
motor.attr('transform', 'rotate(2 ' + (objectwidth / 2) + ' ' + (objectHeight/2) + ')');
```