# Rotate an svg path around its own centre using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, inkscape

I have a SVG path (switch icon) made with Inkscape which I am trying to programatically rotate 90 degrees around its own centre. In my proper web page I have many of these icons all referenced by there ID so this needs to be a generic solution I can apply.

It looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946633/rotate-svg-path-around-its-centre-d3) question is identical but was never followed up by the OP and they where never able to provide any more code or a fiddle.

I have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6p4x0oLf/) which shows everything for my example.

```
knob = d3.select("#switch1")
knob.attr('transform', 'rotate(0 0 0)')
```

Is the basic code I'm using for the rotation. I need to know how I can calculate the x & y values so any given icon can be made to point towards the on/off text as in the example. Or another way to get the same rotation effect using `d3`

If I do `knob.attr('transform', 'rotate(90 0 0)')` then the icon vanishes off the page - I thought `0 0` was to rotate round its relative centre?

If I manually do `knob.attr('transform', 'rotate(90 15 15)')` I can keep it on the page but in the wrong place.

The SVG path is made up of;

```
       <path
       id="switch1"
       style="display:inline;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.12199998;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 35.741778,27.194664 -1.082299,0 0,-8.512001 1.082299,-9e-6 z m -5.563199,-4.274211 a 5.00005,5.000032 0 0 0 9.999999,2e-5 5.00005,5.000032 0 1 0 -9.999999,-2e-5 z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
```

The full SVG mark-up can be found on the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the position of the `<path>` with [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox):

```
const centre = knob.node().getBBox();
```

Then, it's just a matter of calculating its centre:

```
knob.attr("transform", "rotate(" + angle + ", " + 
    (centre.x + centre.width / 2) + ", " + (centre.y + centre.height / 2) + ")");
```

Here `angle` is, obviously, the angle you want.

Here is a demo using your SVG (but smaller), click anywhere in the SVG to rotate the path:

```js
let toggle = 0;
let svg = d3.select("svg")
const knob = d3.select("#switch1")
const centre = knob.node().getBBox();
svg.on("click", function() {
  const angle = (toggle = 1 - toggle) ? 90 : 0;
  knob.attr("transform", "rotate(" + angle + ", " + (centre.x + centre.width / 2) + ", " + (centre.y + centre.height / 2) + ")");
})
```

```css
svg {
 border: 1px solid gray;
 background-color: lavender;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
  xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 50 50" id="svg2" version="1.1" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" sodipodi:docname="bar.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="11.2"
     inkscape:cx="34.921875"
     inkscape:cy="1047.7595"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="true"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1033"
     inkscape:window-x="-4"
     inkscape:window-y="-4"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1">
    <inkscape:grid
       type="xygrid"
       id="grid4157" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       id="switch1"
       style="display:inline;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.12199998;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 35.741778,27.194664 -1.082299,0 0,-8.512001 1.082299,-9e-6 z m -5.563199,-4.274211 a 5.00005,5.000032 0 0 0 9.999999,2e-5 5.00005,5.000032 0 1 0 -9.999999,-2e-5 z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:Sans;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="25.714285"
       y="13.612206"
       id="text4135"
       sodipodi:linespacing="125%"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan4137"
         x="25.714285"
         y="13.612206"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:10px;line-height:125%;font-family:Sans;-inkscape-font-specification:'Sans, Normal';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start">OFF</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:Sans;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="44.566826"
       y="26.086744"
       id="text4135-2"
       sodipodi:linespacing="125%"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan4137-2"
         x="44.566826"
         y="26.086744"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:10px;line-height:125%;font-family:Sans;-inkscape-font-specification:'Sans, Normal';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start">ON</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

You can also add a transition:

```js
let toggle = 0;
let svg = d3.select("svg")
const knob = d3.select("#switch1")
const centre = knob.node().getBBox();
const centreX = centre.x + centre.width / 2;
const centreY = centre.y + centre.height / 2;
svg.on("click", function() {
  const angle = (toggle = 1 - toggle) ? 90 : 0;
  knob.transition()
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attrTween("transform", function() {
      return d3.interpolateString("rotate(" + (90 - angle) + ", " + centreX + ", " + centreY + ")", "rotate(" + angle + ", " + centreX + ", " + centreY + ")")
    })
})
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lavender;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
  xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 50 50" id="svg2" version="1.1" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" sodipodi:docname="bar.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="11.2"
     inkscape:cx="34.921875"
     inkscape:cy="1047.7595"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="true"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1033"
     inkscape:window-x="-4"
     inkscape:window-y="-4"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1">
    <inkscape:grid
       type="xygrid"
       id="grid4157" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       id="switch1"
       style="display:inline;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.12199998;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 35.741778,27.194664 -1.082299,0 0,-8.512001 1.082299,-9e-6 z m -5.563199,-4.274211 a 5.00005,5.000032 0 0 0 9.999999,2e-5 5.00005,5.000032 0 1 0 -9.999999,-2e-5 z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:Sans;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="25.714285"
       y="13.612206"
       id="text4135"
       sodipodi:linespacing="125%"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan4137"
         x="25.714285"
         y="13.612206"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:10px;line-height:125%;font-family:Sans;-inkscape-font-specification:'Sans, Normal';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start">OFF</tspan></text>
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:Sans;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="44.566826"
       y="26.086744"
       id="text4135-2"
       sodipodi:linespacing="125%"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan4137-2"
         x="44.566826"
         y="26.086744"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:10px;line-height:125%;font-family:Sans;-inkscape-font-specification:'Sans, Normal';text-align:start;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:start">ON</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Gerardo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57174169/4235784) shows the obvious and most widely applicable solution there are other ways to do it. This answer has some experimental touch to it (Gerardo reported it to be broken on Safari) as it lays out two not off-the-shelf approaches. Think of it as exploring the possibilities and adding to the knowledge base rather than presenting the idiomatic way.

---

Instead of getting the bounding box and doing some, admittedly, trivial math you can use the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) CSS property to control the origin for an element's transformations. Because Firefox seems to handle this differently you should also set [`transform-box:fill-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box). Setting the origin for the rotation to `50% 50%` will then work as you originally expected rotating the element around its center. Side note: rotating around the center is the default behavior for HTML whereas SVG by default rotates around the coordinates origin.

Here is an even more boiled down version of Gerardo's demo:

```js
let toggle = 0;
const svg = d3.select("svg")
const knob = d3.select("#switch1")
svg.on("click", function() {
  const angle = (toggle = 1 - toggle) ? 90 : 0;
  knob.attr("transform", "rotate(" + angle + ")");
})
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 1.12199998;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%
}

text {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Sans;
  fill: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

  <svg width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <g>
      <path id="switch1"
         d="m 35,27 -1,0 0,-9 1,0 z m -5.7,-4 a 5,5 0 0 0 10,0 5,5 0 1 0 -10,0 z" />
      <text x="26" y="14">OFF</text>
      <text x="45" y="26">ON</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

You can even push the envelope using the *hidden-checkbox-label* trick to do this with no JavaScript at all!

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 1.12199998;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%
}

text {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Sans;
  fill: #000000;
}

#dummy {
  display: none;
}

#dummy:checked+label path {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="dummy">

<label for="dummy">
  <svg width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <g>
      <path id="switch1"
         d="m 35,27 -1,0 0,-9 1,0 z m -5.7,-4 a 5,5 0 0 0 10,0 5,5 0 1 0 -10,0 z" />
      <text x="26" y="14">OFF</text>
      <text x="45" y="26">ON</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</label>
```

Comment: the ON position is a not centered on Firefox (latest) as well

Comment: I'd like to avoid browser related issues, and too much reliance on css, the actual page this is being used on has a massive reliance on JS anyway. But none the less this is actually very interesting for something else I have coming up and this would be an elegant way to keep minimal/no JS for those pages. For some reason your answer never notified me so I've only just seen it.