# How to Draw rectangles at 0,45,90,135,180 degree so on around an SVG Circle with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to draw rectangles at 0,45,90,135,180 degree so on around an SVG Circle with D3.js

with below piece of code I am able to draw rectangle at 0/360 degree

```
var circles = vis.svg.selectAll("circle")
                       .data(circleRadii)
                       .enter()
                       .append("circle");
var circleAttributes = circles
                     .attr("cx", 190)
                     .attr("cy", 190)
                     .attr("r", function (d) { return d; })
                     .style("fill", "none")
                .style("stroke", "red")
                .style("fill", "none");
var chairOriginX = 190 + ((340) * Math.sin(0));
var chairOriginY = 190 - ((340) * Math.cos(0));

var chairWidth = 20;
var chair = vis.svg.append("rect").attr({
     x: chairOriginX - (chairWidth / 2),
     y: chairOriginY - (chairWidth / 2),
     width: chairWidth,
     opacity: 1,
     height: 50,
     fill: "none",
     stroke: "blue"    
});
```

But not sure how to print at `45` , `90` .... degrees

Comment: search for translate and rotate D3 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030473/combining-translate-and-rotate-with-d3

Comment: Its more about rotating a rectangle. I can try this but I am looking for how through `sin` ,`cos` `trigonometry`  I can control the positioning of rectangles .

Comment: just pass the transformation in the parameters for chair. And use the originX & Y (i.e using sin and cos) to manipulate the rotate values ? Set up a fiddle perhaps and ill take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some [trigonometry knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sine.2C_cosine_and_tangent) :

> - the sine of an angle is the ratio of the length of the opposite side to the length of the hypotenuse,
> - the cosine of an angle is the ratio of the length of the adjacent side to the length of the hypotenuse

You can then calculate the position of your rectangles (their upper left corners in this case)

```
.attr('x', function (d) {
    var rad = (ang0 - d.angle) * Math.PI / 180;
    return x0 + Math.sin(rad) * r;
})
.attr('y', function (d) {
    var rad = (ang0 - d.angle) * Math.PI / 180;
    return y0 + Math.cos(rad) * r;
})
```

where `ang0` is the starting angle (0 is at the bottom), `x0` and `y0` the center of your circle, `r` its radius

And a demo

```js
var squares = [
    {angle: 45, color: 'red'},
    {angle: 90, color: 'green'},
    {angle: 180, color: 'blue'},
    {angle: 225, color: 'yellow'},
];

var x0 = 190, y0 = 190, r= 100, w = 20, h= 50, ang0 = 180;
d3.select('svg').selectAll("rect").data(squares)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)
    .attr('x', function (d) {
        var rad = (ang0 - d.angle) * Math.PI / 180;
        return x0 + Math.sin(rad) * r;
    })
    .attr('y', function (d) {
        var rad = (ang0 - d.angle) * Math.PI / 180;
        return y0 + Math.cos(rad) * r;
    })
    .attr('fill', function(d) {return d.color; })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width='300' height='300'>
   <circle cx='190' cy='190' r='100' fill='none' stroke='red'></circle>
</svg>
```

If you want to rotate your rectangles, you can add a `transform` attribute. For example :

```
.attr('transform', function(d) {
    var x = this.getAttribute('x'),
        y = this.getAttribute('y');
    
    return "rotate ("+ d.angle +" "+ x +" "+ y +")"
});
```

or, if you want you rectangles tangential to the circle,

```
.attr('x', function (d) {
    var rad = (ang0 - d.angle) * Math.PI / 180;
    return x0 + Math.sin(rad) * r - w/2 ;
})
.attr('y', function (d) {
    var rad = (ang0 - d.angle) * Math.PI / 180;
    return y0 + Math.cos(rad) * r;
})
.attr('fill', function(d) {return d.color; })
.attr('transform', function(d) {
    var x = parseInt(this.getAttribute('x'), 10) + w/2,
        y = parseInt(this.getAttribute('y'), 10);

    return "rotate ("+ (180 + d.angle)+" "+ x +" "+ y+")"
})
```

```js
var squares = [
    {angle: 45, color: 'red'},
    {angle: 90, color: 'green'},
    {angle: 180, color: 'blue'},
    {angle: 225, color: 'yellow'},
];

var x0 = 190, y0 = 190, r= 100, w = 20, h= 50, ang0 = 180;
d3.select('svg').selectAll("rect").data(squares)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)
    .attr('x', function (d) {
        var rad = (ang0 - d.angle) * Math.PI / 180;
        return x0 + Math.sin(rad) * r - w/2 ;
    })
    .attr('y', function (d) {
        var rad = (ang0 - d.angle) * Math.PI / 180;
        return y0 + Math.cos(rad) * r;
    })
    .attr('fill', function(d) {return d.color; })
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
        var x = parseInt(this.getAttribute('x'), 10) + w/2,
            y = parseInt(this.getAttribute('y'), 10);
    
        return "rotate ("+ (180 + d.angle)+" "+ x +" "+ y+")"
    })
    ;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width='500' height='500'>
   <circle cx='190' cy='190' r='100' fill='none' stroke='red'></circle>
  <line x1="190" y1="0"  x2="190" y2="400" stroke="black" />
  <line x1="0" y1="190"  x2="400" y2="190" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This solution looks good , I will try and comment. Only thing I need to rotate rectangles to place them properly over the circle

Comment: You could add a `transform` attribute with a rotate definition based on the angle you have. I've added an example

Comment: It worked for me , just one query I tried to modify rotate `angle` to place the rectangles facing not towards center of the circle , basically facing outside the circle. `return "rotate ("+ d.angle*2 +" "+ x +" "+ y +")"` . But its not working for all the rectangles

Comment: Got an issue here , I have increased `r` for rectangles and set it `150` from `100` . Now all the rectangles are lying above the sphere/circle. Now in case my rectangles height is not fixed they are inconsistently creating a gap between the sphere and rectangle. Please check the `fiddle` here https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/6ffg2fuL/

Comment: You didn't modify the radius in the HTML https://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/6ffg2fuL/1/ And if you want to to have outward facing rects, just add 180 degrees  to your rotation `rotate ("+ (180+d.angle) +" "+ x +" "+ y +")` https://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/6ffg2fuL/2/

Comment: Hi nikoshr,  I got a query here https://jsfiddle.net/xcn35ycm/ why the negative height bar and positive height bar space difference is not universal.

Comment: Very nice example, but with D3 v6 it doesn't work: "Cannot read property 'attr' of null", and I can't understand why

Comment: @Paolovip D3 used to allow setting multiple attributes in the same method `.attr({width: w, height:h})` and that seems to be no longer the case. I've modified my examples and here's a Fiddle with D3 6.6

Comment: @nikoshr Thank you, but it was my mistake. I don't know why, but now it works fine. Now I must learn how to change the height of rectangles with socket.io (and many other things). Thank you again, your sample was very useful for me.